# Disable/Enable UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uibutton, conditional-statements

I am trying to create different levels within a game. At the moment the user can click into any level and play that level. I want to prevent the User from clicking level 2 unless they have passed level 1.

I have a class VC which at the end of a level says level passed, clear next level. 
In here I will have a counter so if counter = 1 clear level 2 etc.

I am unsure how to make a button clickable or not. I want the unlocked level to not be clickable and be a slightly different colour until they have passed the previous level.

Any ideas on how to do this? I am also open to a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

The more traditional Objective-C syntax:

```
[button setEnabled:YES];
```

and,

```
[button setEnabled:NO];
```

Answer (score 2):

I would unset the enabled state of the buttons for levels 2 and over through Interface Builder. That way, the default state is disabled.

Then, only when they have met the requirement, set the enabled state of the buttons to YES.

You'll want to save the fact that they met the requirement so that you can set the state of the buttons properly whenever the view loads.

Look at the `UserDefaults` class for easily saving user data.

Answer (score 0):

To disable the button use below code:

```
button.enabled = NO;
```

To identify the button, give it a tag with the level of your stage.

```
button.tag = LEVEL_OF_STAGE;
```

To retrieve the button from parentView,

```
UIButton *btn = [parentView viewWithTag:STAGE_NUMBER];
```